# PHP- delete/unlink a file using an domain path

Tags: php

how can I delete a file using an url path ?
I have

```
$file_with_path = "http://www.myweb.com/uploads/audio.mp3";
if (file_exists($file_with_path)) {
  unlink($file_with_path);
}
```

I don't use "/uploads/audio.mp3" or similar directory paths due some reasons.

thanks in advance !!

Comment: `Absolute path` means absolute path on you __local__ filesystem and not with domain name. Usually `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is used.

Comment: my fault, I just edited it.

Comment: You __cannot__ delete files with domain path. It's absolutely __insecure__

Comment: okay, thank you  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlink` tells the **operating system** to delete a given file. The OS identifies files by file system path - it does not interact with URLs in any way. URLs are translated to file system paths by the **web server**, which is an entirely different piece of software. While theoretically there is a way to tell a web server to delete the file (by sending a HTTP DELETE request), no web server is going to honor that - it would be way too insecure. It is relatively easy to control who can access the file system; it is very hard to control who can send requests to the web server.

In short, you will have to figure out what the file system path for the file is, and use `unlink` (and `file_exists`) with that path.